# How to delete a row where there are only one of the kind in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data in MySQL table named info:

```
chapter | section
     3  | 0 
     3  | 1
     3  | 2
     3  | 3
     4  | 0
     5  | 0
```

I would like to delete a row for chapter = n, but only when there is no section>0 for same chapter.  So chapter 3 can't be deleted while chapter 4 and 5 can.  I know the following doesn't work:

`DELETE info WHERE chapter = 3 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM info WHERE chapter = 3 AND section>0)`;

The same table is used twice in the statement.  So what is the easiest way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the idea right. Here is the syntax:

```
DELETE
FROM mytable
WHERE chapter NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        select tt.chapter
        from mytable tt
        where tt.section <> 0
        group by tt.chapter
    ) tmp
)
```

The nested select is a workaround a bug in MySQL.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc347/1)

Comment: I checked in MySQL and it did work.  I need to only delete a chapter = n, for which is easy to add that condition in WHERE with AND.  So I regarded this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You can run a sub query to return the rows that have sections of more then one and then delete the rows returned from the sub query.**

---

`DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.chapter Not IN (select chapter from 
(SELECT table1.chapter FROM table1 WHERE Table1.section >=1 ) Results);`

---

[Example Fiddle based on your question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28504f/1/0)

**You could also supply the chapter  as well in the sub query where clause if you only want to delete a specfic chapter. If it does not meet the where clause then no records will be deleted.**

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

`DELETE FROM Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM Table t2
   Where t2.chapter = t.chapter
   And t2.section > 0
)`

In my experience `Exists` generally performs better than `In`.  If you  are storing a large amount of records you should take this into consideration.